# What's the difference between the 2 debug buttons in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, ubuntu-16.04

In my vscode (with cpp tools), I see 2 debug buttons on the status bar (attached).

One is on the left, it's called `(gdb)Launch ()`
The other one is in the middle, it's called `Debug`

Why there are 2 buttons, what's the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the left debug button will use `launch.json`, it's same to the top left green triangle button; but the right button will not use `launch.json`.